# Communicating via RS232 cable in Win 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, serial-port, usbserial

I have been trying to communicate to a device via an RS232 cable and Win8 does not recognize the device. It recognizes it when I use a USB cable instead but I would like it to work both ways. Is this possible or does Windows 8 not support serial communication?

Comment: Can you give us more detail on the code you're using to operate with RS232?

Comment: I believe plug and play has never worked with RS232.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'recognize the device' it *sounds like* you're expecting the RS232 connected device to act like a plug-n-play device?

Plug-N-Play requires some auto-negotiation and in some cases auto-configuration. While legacy RS-232 communication can support the P-n-P negotiations, it's quite the exception to find a device that implements this interface and is P-n-P compatible as RS-232 is getting long in the tooth and short on available bandwidth.

**Unless there's a specific driver loaded for that device on your system, and your RS-232 cable is wired appropriately (DTR/CTS), there's no native operating system mechanism to detect that a serial RS-232 connected device is attached via the port.**

The device manufacturer *could* write a driver that would detect the device on a RS-232 port and auto-negotiate the port settings appropriately.

*Look at it this way, what you're expecting is for the OS to know about every device made by every manufacturer in every configuration since the dawn of the PC era. Only the manufacturer, or intrepid engineers with open source information about the device can make it 'plug-n-play' for a given operating system.*